# match value from column A Data frame A to cloumn B in Data frame B and create list of none matches from Dataframe A using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to get a list of Values [ID] from Column A in Data Frame A that does not match Value [ID] from Column B in Data Frame B. Data Frame A, Column A will only have 1 instance of the Value - where as Data Frame B, Column B can have multiple instance of the Value.

I want to come away with a dataframe that has all the rows from Data Frame A where the Value was NOT Matched in Data Frame B.

This is what I got - but it has to many matches.

```
def get_hours_id(labor_excel, people_excel):
    df = pd.read_excel(labor_excel)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(people_excel)
    internal_id_people_list = df1['ID']
    internal_id_list = df['ID']
    non_match_id = set(internal_id_people_list).difference(internal_id_list)
    for id in non_match_id:
        result = df1[df1['ID'] == id]
        print(result)
```

Data Frame A

```
Column A      Column B     Column C 
int(123)      name(mike)   department A
int(234)      name(Joe)    department B
int(567)      name(Jane)   department A
```

Data Frame B

```
Column A      Column B     Column C 
int(123)      name(mike)   department A
int(123)      name(Mike)   department A
int(567)      name(Jane)   department B
int(567)      name(Jane)   department B
int(567)      name(Jane)   department B
```

New Data Frame (results)

```
Column A      Column B     Column C 
int(234)      name(Joe)    department B
```

Comment: `dfA[~dfA['Column A'].isin(dfB['Column A'])]`?

Comment: Yup that totally works - my only concerns is that I am looking at 10k rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your data but if the dataframes are big the best solution might be to do a simple join and delete things that have matched

```
df_B['flag'] = 1
unmacthed = df_A.merge(df_B, how='left').query('flag != flag')
unmacthed = unmacthed.drop('flag',axis=1)
```

Comment: Ok let me try this out.